# jQuery file upload What is the actual Idea to use it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

**jQuery file upload** is beautiful and nice to use. But I am not sure what is the actual idea/ process.

1. Customer fill the form (order).
2. Customer must attach an **image**.
3. Customer choose image file and the **jQuery file upload is working**.

And what next ?

**Method 1**
Should I let jQuery file upload put the file into server first.
Then when customer submit the whole order how can I get that image name to insert to this order ? I need that image name to insert in this order and use it later.

**OR..**

**Method 2**
I use jQuery file upload just for beautiful thing and let customer see the beautiful progress bar and maybe preview their image. Then I must send the whole thing ( image file + string data) to server with the normal way ? Then what is the use for jQuery file upload ?

Here is my script that I stuck with the idea what actually I have to do.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="progress_style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="upload_progress.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="PHPURL" id="myFormmm" name="frmupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="upload_file" name="upload_file" />
  <input type="submit" name='submit_image' value="Submit Comment" onclick='upload_image();'/>
</form>
<div class='progress' id="progress_div">
<div class='bar' id='bar'></div>
<div class='percent' id='percent1'>0%</div>
</div>
<div id='output_image'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**progress bar script**

```
  function upload_image()
{
  var bar = $('#bar');
  var percent = $('#percent');
  $('#myFormmm').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {
      document.getElementById("progress_div").style.display="block";
      var percentVal = '0%';
      bar.width(percentVal);
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },

    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
      bar.width(percentVal);
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },

    success: function() {
      var percentVal = '100%';
      bar.width(percentVal)
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },

    complete: function(xhr) {
      if(xhr.responseText)
      {
        document.getElementById("output_image").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_image']))
{
  $uploadfile=$_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"];
  $folder="test/";
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"], $folder.$_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);
  echo '<img src="'.$folder."".$_FILES["upload_file"]["name"].'">';
  exit();
}
```

**UPDATE**
I am able to fix my problem. Let customer upload file first and see at the beautiful progress bar :D Then they submit the rest string data.

After that I use PHP code glob($directory.'*') to pull everything in image folder and compare with image name in database. Then Delete everything in folder that is not listed in database.

Here is my code:
$

```
directory = "MY DIRECTORY/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory.'*');

foreach($images as $image) {
   $name = explode('_',$image);
   $name = $name[0];
     $file = basename($name);



  $stmt= $conn->prepare("SELECT img_name FROM tb_img WHERE img_name=:img_name");
   $stmt->bindParam(':img_name',$file);
   $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() < 1 ){

            unlink($image);
}
}
```

I am very satisfied with this. But I don´t dare to mark this solution as the **solved solution** Because I really don´t know what other people do. Maybe my method looks stupid for those who know better than me.

Comment: You can use it however you want, but your first way sounds the best IMHO. You can also have the customer upload and then you attach the image’s (potentially temporary) path to the cart/order/session/whatever for use however you need it later.

Comment: Thank ! I appreciate it. I know this question may sounds stupid. But I am not sure which method is the normal way that people do. => If I go with method 1 : there will be uwanted files that people just uploaded and not be deleted store in folder. for example upload and just do not continue to complete the from and leave the page. => if I go with method 2 I can just forget the problem with unwanted files but the loading time for submit data will be long. And the jQuery file upload will be just useless beautiful thing for this page.

Comment: And that’s why I said “potentially temporary". As part of your checkout or finalization process you can move good ones to a permanent location, and have a cron job purge items that are older than _n_ based on your internal logic.

Comment: I found out :) => First I follow the first method. Upload the file first - then string data.
...Then use PHP code : **glob($directory.'*')** to list all the file that is not exist in my database. Then.....Boom Every unwanted file is gone. Anyway thank you for your kindness. Nobody like to answer question like mine. But you.